# Tkinter both 'sticky' and 'rowconfigure' did not fill the empty space

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, window, tkinter-layout

I have 2 frames inside root which called "header_frame" and "activity_frame" both are in the same column which is "column=0". I want both frames to be resizeable matching its root parent filling all empty space like this :

[image: expected layout]

I have tried all grid config possibilities including setting 'rowconfigure' on 'root', set activity_frame to stick on "North" which is header_frame, last but not least I've also tried to stick header_frame to south which is the result I do not want because those frame share same size (I hope header_frame has 'maxsize' attribute but sadly it didn't have). so this is the code that I've tried :

```
self.root = root
self.column = ""
self.search = ""
self.root.minsize(500,480)
self.comboboxValue = None
self.root.title("CUCI (CSV Unique Column Identifier)")
self.root.configure(background="powder blue")
self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
self.root.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)

#header frame
self.header_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
self.header_frame.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky="NEW")
self.header_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
self.header_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
self.header_frame.configure(background="grey")

#activity Frame
self.activity_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
self.activity_frame.grid(row=1, column=0,sticky="NEWS")
self.activity_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
self.activity_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
self.activity_frame.configure(background="grey",pady=1)
```

Here's the layout result from my code which I do not expect:
[image]

The point is that I want to fill those empty spaces with activity_frame to be stick-ed on 'header_frame'.Please I do not wish to use pack(self.activity_frame.pack(fill=tk.X)). I just want to use grid because it's easy to use

Comment: I also have tried using self.header_frame.grid_propagate(0). but no luck

Comment: calling `grid_propagate(0)` is almost never the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the gap is because you don't have the header frame stick to the bottom of the space it was given. If you change the `sticky` attribute for the header to be "nsew" you'll see that the header fills the extra space.

```
self.header_frame.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky="nesw")
```

I'm guessing you don't want the header frame to be so tall. If that is the case, give row 0 a weight of 0 instead of 1. That way all extra unallocated space will be given to row 1.

```
self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=0)
```

After doing so, and after adding a couple of other widgets to simulate your screen, this is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: i've already mentioned that in the question above. and that space is replaced by header_frame background which is grey. now the empty space is grey coloured if I do what you told me

Comment: @AbdullahSaid: I don't understand your comment. With these changes you get a small header, and all of the remaining space is the activity frame. Isn't that what you want? I don't know what you mean when you say "header_activity background" - what is "header_activity"?

Comment: exactly. that's the point. I just want to expand the scrolled text bar if I do vertical window resizing

Comment: @AbdullahSaid: then this code does exactly what you want - small  header and the rest of the area filled with the activity frame.

Comment: oops typo. what i mean is header_frame (containing all the button except scrolled text). now how do i replace those blue gap with scrolled text bar on activity_frame

Comment: Your example code doesn't have a scrolled text widget or any of the other widgets. With my changes, however, the grey activity frame will fill the majority of the window, with only a small part above for the header frame.

Comment: because, i've already written about 400 lines of code. it will be hard to read if I embed everything. the main problem is in the frame only. because the grey color represent how large the frame was. but the gap show blue color from root

Comment: My answer does exactly what you want with the code you posted - a minimal header frame, with the activity frame filling all of the rest of the window. There is no gap if yo do what is in my answer.

Comment: I just did try that. and the same result with rowconfigure weight set to zero also the sticky attribute. here I provide you the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/IDW3uoS

Comment: I can only work with the code you give us. My changes to the code you posted will do exactly what you want.

Comment: oh my, i just put the zero weight on wrong frame, thank you very much!